# Playing pausing and stopping sounds with soundcloud javascript sdk

Tags: javascript, sdk, soundcloud

my sound is playing when i click the button but it doesnt pause or stop when i reclick it. The alert showing the else block is working however so i'm thinking its the second sc.stream. see code below:

```
var i = $('.song').attr('id');
var is_playing = false;

$('.song').click(function(){
    if(is_playing == false){
        SC.stream('/tracks/'+i).then(function(player){
            player.play();
        });
        is_playing = true;
    } else {
        SC.stream('/tracks/'+i).then(function(player){
            player.pause();
        });
        alert('This alert works when is_playing is true');
        is_playing = false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently creating two separate streams (and two separate `player` objects). You will need to create the player first and make it available outside the callback, for example by storing it in a global var:

```
var i = $('.song').attr('id');
var is_playing = false;
var player;
SC.stream('/tracks/'+i).then(function(stream){
            player = stream;
        });

$('.song').click(function(){
    if(is_playing == false){
        player.play();
        is_playing = true;
    } else {
        player.pause();
        alert('This alert works when is_playing is true');
        is_playing = false;
    }
});
```

Comment: one last question sorry... i wanted to find out if its possible to set it up so many tracks can play from various play buttons on the page using this function?

Comment: Yes that's possible. You would need to create a stream for every button (perhaps on the first press) and make every player object available.